# Convergence radius of sum using sin

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I have to find the convergence interval of the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sin(2n)x^n$$
as $R=\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_{n}/a_{n+1}|$, I got
$$R=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{\sin(2n)}{\sin(2(n+1))}\right|$$

But there's my problem. I tried:
$$\sin(2n)=2\sin(n)\cos(n)$$
and
$$\sin(2(n+1))=2\sin(n+1)\cos(n+1)$$
or
$$\sin(2(n+1))=\sin(2n+2)=\sin(2n)\cos(2)+\sin(2)\cos(2n)$$
but for both above, I couldn't find any way to cancel something and then solve the limit. Is there another expression I could using about $\sin(2(n+1))$ or is there something I'm forgetting about what I'm doing?

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/a/518415/108128

Comment: The sum is $\dfrac{x \sin 2}{x^2-2 x \cos 2+1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The radius of convergence $R$ satisfies the property that if $|x| < R$ then the series converges and if $|x| < R$ then the series diverges.

Also, you can express $\sum_{n=0}^N\sin(2n)$ as the real part of $\sum_{n=0}^Ne^{2in}$.