# Calculation of radius of convergence of a power series

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

For power series $ \sum a_nx^n $ we can calculate the raduis of convergence using the ratio( $\lim_{n \to ∞}| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| <1) $  and root test $(\lim_{n \to ∞}|(a_n)|^{1/n}<1)$ and from here we get a range for $x$ for which the series is convergent.

But how to deal with $$ \sum (x \sin \frac{πn}{3})^n$$
If we apply the above tests on this, it seems strange to me,

For $| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = | \frac{ \sin((n+1)π/3)}{\sin (nπ/3)} |
 \implies | \frac{ \sin((n+1)π/3)}{\sin (nπ/3)} | < 1$

Which gives Radius of convergence R, $ - \frac{\sin(nπ/3)}{\sin (n+1)π/3)}
< R< \frac{\sin(nπ/3)}{\sin (n+1)π/3)}$

Now how to proceed further?

Simlar procedure for, $|( \sin \frac{πn}{3})^n|^{1/n} < 1  \implies |( \sin \frac{πn}{3})|<1  $

Which gives $ \frac{-1}{ \sin \frac{πn}{3}} <R< \frac{1}{ \sin \frac{πn}{3}}$

How to proceed now? I think there might be some other approach. I  [found](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/518403/1183233) a similar question but there is difference in both these questions.

How to calculate the raduis of convergence for these type of series?

Kindly help, Thank You

Comment: The coefficients $a_n,\,n\in\mathbb{N}$ do not contain the variable $x.$ First,  recognise the coefficients and the center of the power series and then use the limit to find the radius and the interval of the convergence.

Comment: Sorry for using that, I just took the whole series term including $x$ powers in formula and thats why a $x$ was remained in that,  but I have edited that part now. But how to recognise the coefficient, the $ \sin nπ/3$ function have $n$ in it?

Answer (score 3):

Let $\lambda =\lim\sup|a_n|^{1/n}$ where $a_n=\sin^n(\frac{n\pi}{3})$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ . Now Radius of convergence defined by $R=\frac{1}{\lambda}$ when $\lambda \neq 0$.

$$\lambda=\lim\sup|\sin^n(\frac{n\pi}{3})|^{1/n}=\lim\sup|\sin(\frac{n\pi}{3})|=1$$

Therefore  $R=1$.

Refer https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RadiusofConvergence.html .

Comment: But how can we say that it's lim sup will be 1? Because I see that it have 3 limit points $√3/2 ,-√3/2 , 0 $

Comment: @Gajjze Refer that site